# Undeclared exceptions in JNI

Tags: java, exception, java-native-interface, throw

What happens if a JNI dll throws a Java exception, and the java method definition doesn't declare that exception (no **throws** clause)?

Code:

```
private native void jniDoSomething(int someValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception will be thrown anyway.
Just have checked this.

I think such behaviour is because that `throws` keyword doesn't affect the native code anyway. There is no ability to check if the native code throws the appropriate exception and even in header file there are no mentioning about exceptions.

Comment: Similar problem exists with Class.newInstance() method, which also allows to throw undeclared exceptions.

Comment: Yes, my problem was something different, the exception name was wrong, the native function couldn't find the class, and threw no exception at all.